# Get name (address) of computer from which from which SSH login was made

Tags: linux, ssh

After logging onto a linux machine via SSH, I would like to be able to retrieve the name of the computer from which the connection was made.  Ideally I am looking for some command like `hostname` or `uname` but that would retrieve the name of the client instead of the host.

This information must be accessible somewhere, since when I log on I get a message that contains the clinent name from the last login:

`Last login: Thu Mar 11 18:42:01 2010 from my.address.com`

The reason for wanting to do this is to be able to take different action in my `.login` file depending on which computer I am currently connecting from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer:

`who -m`

For bonus marks (yes, this is filthy, someone please leave a comment as to how to do it better):

`who -m | awk '{print $5;}' | sed s/\(// | sed s/\)//`

Comment: @amicitas: Check again, I made it better :D Upvote if it helped you!

Comment: Thanks, I was about to spend the next 30 minutes trying to remember how to use awk and sed again.

Comment: @amicitas: My cleanup (for the parentheses) was quick-and-dirty, but it should do the job. You might even be able to get a raw IP from `who` instead of an FQDN; check the `who` manpage. This way you could adjust your .login so as to achieve "if logging in from 17.x.x.x (Apple, Inc.) then do $FOO", as not all of Apple's IPs may have PTR records ending in `.apple.com`.

Comment: This is even cleaner :-): who -m | awk -F '[()]' '{print $2}'

Comment: Also note that there is a more reliable variable: SSH_CLIENT has the client IP address (and server and client port). SSH_CONNECTION adds the server IP address.

Comment: @janmoesen you should make an answer based on the variables you mention - it works better for me than the current correct answer.